# Is there a mathematical connection between Zipf’s Law and the Birthday Problem?

Tags: statistics

According the the Wikipedia article on Zipf’s Law, a mere 135 words suffices to cover 50% of the Brown Corpus, and according to the Wikipedia article on the Birthday Problem, a mere 23 randomly-chosen people suffices to have a probability > 50% that two of them will have the same birthday (month and day, ignoring leap years). Is this merely a coincidence? Or is there some underlying mathematical reason for the Pareto-Principle-like behavior of these two phenomena? Does the Pareto Principle in fact explain them both?

Comment: I'd say it's more related to benford's law for Zipf's case ( see the wikipedia references) and numberphile has a video on benford's law , as to the birthday problem  numberphile has a video on that one as well :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2ey9a70yY0&t=7s

Comment: What is the coincidence? $23$ is not the same number as $135$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I guess the said coincidence is related the number **50** (from few words, few days we get **half** of...).

Comment: @Pedro : So you ask how many words does it take to account for $50\%$ of  the Brown Corpus and you come up with some number, and then you ask how many people do you need in order to get a probability of at least $50\%$ that at least two of them have the same birthday and you come up with some number. Where's the coincidence in that?

Comment: @MichaelHardy For both questions, the answer is a small number. Probably, less than our intuition would expect. This is why the word "mere" is used in the OP post.

Comment: @Pedro : To me, $135$ for the Brown Corpus doesn't seem the least bit surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no.

There is an analogue to the birthday problem that we could do with text. It would be "what is the minimum number of words we can draw randomly from a corpus such that the probability that two of them is the same is greater than $50\%$?". Not sure what the number would be, but since this post at present has three "is"'s in it and only about 60 words, I'm guessing we could expect it to be between $0$ and $60$ for the corpus of everything I've ever written on MathSE.

The fact that the birthday problem has a value (23) in the same range is pretty much a coincidence. There are many more words than days of the year, so we might expect it to be much higher than $23$, but the fact that each word is not nearly equally likely (i.e. Zipf's law) pushes the value down again.

So Zipf's law (which is about the relative frequency of the words) has a big effect on the answer to the text analogue of the birthday problem, but it's a different phenomenon.

The usual birthday problem assumes trivial rank-frequency characteristics. We assume every birthday is equally likely. So the fact that we get a counterintuitive answer doesn't have anything to do with rank-frequency / Zipfs law. Rather it has to do with how the pigeonhole principle becomes important rather quickly. This is true with words as much as is is with birthdays... the fact that words have a more interesting distribution than birthdays is unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

There may be psychological similarities in that surprisingly few things make something likely, but that belongs on another site.  The English word case just comes about because some words are much more common than other words, so if you add up the frequencies of the most common words you get to $50\%$ rather quickly.  The birthday paradox comes about because each pair of birthdays has $\frac 1{365}$ chance to match.  As you add more people into the mix, the number of pairs goes up as the square of the number of people.  The number to get a match is then about $\sqrt {365} \approx 19$.  Here the birthdays are equally probable, there are just more chances for a match than people recognize.